# The mechanism behind multiple assignment in Python

Tags: python, multiple-assignment, parallel-assignment

We all know multiple assignment can assign multiple variables **at one time**, and it is useful in swap. 
It works well in this situation:

```
nums = [2, 0, 1]
nums[0], nums[2] = nums[2], nums[0]
# nums=[1, 0, 2] directly, correct
```

, but it failed in more complex situation, such as:

```
nums = [2, 0, 1]
nums[0], nums[nums[0]] = nums[nums[0]], nums[0]
# nums=[1, 2, 1] directly, incorrect

nums = [2, 0, 1]
tmp = nums[0]
nums[0], nums[tmp] = nums[tmp], nums[0]
# nums=[1, 0, 2] with temporary variable, correct
```

It seems in `nums[nums[0]]`, `nums[0]` will be assigned **before**, not at one time.
it also failed in complex linklist node swap, such as:

```
cur.next, cur.next.next.next, cur.next.next = cur.next.next, cur.next, cur.next.next.next
# directly, incorrect

pre = cur.next
post = cur.next.next
cur.next, post.next, pre.next = post, pre, post.next
# with temporary variable, correct
```

So I want to know the **mechanism** behind multiple assignment in Python, and what is the **Best Practices** for this, temporary variable is the only way?

Comment: probably relevant: https://www.quora.com/How-does-multiple-assignment-work-in-Python

Comment: This is an issue of evaluation order. The order of evaluation in an assignment that has subscription of the same array on both sides has a non obvious order. It is such that `c, b = b, c` is not the same as `a = b, c; c, b = a`. I wish I could remember which other question had covered this.

Comment: Should rename this to *"Multiple assignment involving the same Python list elements and indices"*

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
a, b = c, d
```

is equivalent to

```
temp = (c, d)
a = temp[0]  # Expression a is evaluated here, not earlier
b = temp[1]  # Expression b is evaluated here, not earlier
```

Personally I would recommend to write complex assignments explicitly with temporary variables as you showed it.

Another way is to carefully choose the order of the elements in the assignment:

```
nums[nums[0]], nums[0] = nums[0], nums[nums[0]]
```

Changes `nums` as you expect.

Comment: That equivalent is false. `a, b = c, d` is not equal to `e = c, d; a, b = e`.

Comment: @DanD. counter-example?

Comment: The code in the question is that. If the two were equivalent, the question would not have been asked.

Comment: @DanD. `temp = nums[nums[0]], nums[0]; nums[0], nums[nums[0]] = temp` produces the same result as the `nums[0], nums[nums[0]] = nums[nums[0]], nums[0]` from the question.

Comment: Thanks a lot, so I think the concise way is to attention to the order, such as  `cur.next.next.next, cur.next.next, cur.next = cur.next, cur.next.next.next, cur.next.next`

Comment: @DanD. `a, b = c, d` is the same as `a, b = (c, d)`. The right hand side is just a tuple which is evaluated first and could then be assigned to a temporary variable instead. The actual tuple unpacking magic happens after that in the same way, regardless if `a, b = (c, d)` directly or `e = (c, d); a, b = e` indirectly.

Comment: Yeah, I think I agree with @MichaelButscher, right hand side pack to a tuple, and the assignment order of left hand cause the problem, refer to https://www.quora.com/How-does-multiple-assignment-work-in-Python