# why the swapping does not take place when indices are 0 and 1?

Tags: python, list, indexing, swap

I have an unordered array consisting of consecutive integers  `[1, 2, 3, ..., n]` without any duplicates. It is allowed to swap any two elements. I need to find the minimum number of swaps required to sort the array in ascending order.

Starting from the first element of the list, I try to put them in their right position (for example if the first element is 7 it should be in the 6th position of the list). To go one by one in the list, I make a copy, and do the swapping in the second list.

```
a = [4,3,1,2]
b = a[:]
swap = 0
for p in a:
  if (p!= b[p-1]):
    b[p-1], b[b.index(p)] =  b[b.index(p)], b[p-1]
    swap+=1
print(swap)
```

this code works, except for the case that I have to swap two elements in the list whose position is either 0 or 1, in this case . which I don't understand why?? since I'm not exceeding the limit.

Can anyone please explain to me why this happens?

For example, if I print p,  two indices where swapping happens, updated list of b and updated number of swaps:

```
p = 4
idx1= 3 idx2= 0
b= [2, 3, 1, 4]
swap = 1
p = 3
idx1= 2 idx2= 1
b= [2, 1, 3, 4]
swap = 2
p = 1
idx1= 0 idx2= 1
b= [2, 1, 3, 4]
swap = 3
p = 2
idx1= 1 idx2= 0
b= [1, 2, 3, 4]
swap = 4
```

In this case, you can see that for p = 1, when indices are 0 and 1, the swapping is not taking place.

I changed the order of b[p-1], b[b.index(p)] and I don't have the same problem anymore, but I don't understand the reason.

Comment: Can you specify what error you are encountering?

Comment: You have an unordered array consisting of *consecutive* integers? Wouldn't that make the array ordered?

Comment: can you show an example when you see an error?

Comment: This is hard to follow.  First, you haven't shown us the code that produces the output trace you posted: the posted code has only the one `print` at the end.  We don't know when those values are produced.  Second, you say that you've changed the code and that it now works.  I've tried inserting `print`s where *I* would put them, but I don't get your given output.

Comment: There have been a lot of questions like this recently. The short answer is, stop trying to do complex swaps like this. Compute `b.index(p)` first, *then* do your `a, b = b, a`-style swap.

Answer (score 0):

I have encountered the same problem before, and stucked for a while. The reason to cause this is the order of multiple assignment.

```
b[p-1], b[b.index(p)] =  b[b.index(p)], b[p-1]
```

Actually multiple assignment is not exactly assign at the same time. pack and unpack mechanism behind this. so it will change `b[p-1]` first, and `b.index(p)` in `b[b.index(p)]` will be find a new index which is `p-1` when the case `p=1 idx1=0 idx2=1`

if you change the assignment order, it will work fine.

```
b[b.index(p)], b[p - 1] = b[p - 1], b[b.index(p)]
```

or calculate idx first:

```
idx1, idx2 = p - 1, b.index(p)
b[idx1], b[idx2] = b[idx2], b[idx1]
```

I recommend the second version, because first version will do `index` twice. cost twice time than second version.

you can refer to my related question here: [The mechanism behind mutiple assignment in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/q/55369076/11263560)

---

by the way, I think your algorithm is inefficient here, to decrease swap time, but use O(n) `index` operation, and also copy a array here. I think you can use the same idea,  just swap in orignal array.